# React weird code injection after import gives error messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, build

I have been working on a webapp locally and everything is working flawless. But whenever I run `npm run build` I get the following error message in my console.

> ERROR in ./app/containers/Dashboard/Dashboard.js 42:27 Module parse
> failed: Unexpected keyword 'var' (42:27) You may need an appropriate
> loader to handle this file type. | import BookDay from
> "components/BookDay/BookDay"; | import PatientOverview from
> "components/PatientOverview/PatientOverview";
>
> > import TreatmentPlanner, { var _ref = | /*#**PURE***/ | _jsx(ContentWidget, {}, void 0, _jsx(TreatmentPlanner, {})); } from "components/TreatmentPlanner/TreatmentPlanner";  @
> > ./app/containers/PracticePage/PracticePage.js 40:0-55 58:5-14  @
> > ./app/containers/PracticePage/Loadable.js  @
> > ./app/containers/App/App.js  @ ./app/app.js  @ multi
> > ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js ./app/app.js Child
> > __offline_serviceworker:

My imports look like this:

```
import ForegroundBlobWrapper from "basicComponents/ForegroundBlob/ForegroundBlobWrapper";
import BookDay from "components/BookDay/BookDay";
import PatientOverview from "components/PatientOverview/PatientOverview";
import TreatmentPlanner from "components/TreatmentPlanner/TreatmentPlanner";
import PlannedAppointments from "components/PlannedAppointments/PlannedAppointments";
import PageTitle from "components/PageTitle/PageTitle";
```

Also my linter is showing me a very weird problem on the line it is breaking (the import of TreatmentPlanner).

```
import TreatmentPlanner from "components/TreatmentPlanner/TreatmentPlanner";
```

Linter error:
[image]

I have tried to find out what the problem is, but I honestly do not know what could be causing this.

**EDIT:**

Found out that the issue might be a styled component, The Treatmentplanner is wrapped inside a styled component called ContentWidget, which is empty. But when I change this to a normal div, it works again? I am even more confused right now.

Comment: Did you use create-react-app to create your project?

Comment: @S.Haviv No the project uses a react boilerplate https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

Comment: https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_webpack_starter that's what you need.

Comment: Do you think there might be another sollution? Because this only happens when some components are imported, most of the time it just builds on production

Comment: That linter error shows that line 20 doesn't end with quotes and semi-colon. Is this the case?

Comment: @rrd No, in the screenshot below the error message you can see that is has been closed. I added an EDIT: part in my question, maybe the error is somewhere there?